# How to read the contents of a C-style array with only a pointer to it?

Tags: arrays, c++11

Let's say I have :

```
class foo {
private:
    int data[5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

public:
    int* getpData () {
        return data;
    }

    unsigned int getDataByteLength () {
        return 5 * (sizeof(unsigned int));
    }
};
```

I don't have access to `data` and I want to compute the sum of all of `data` elements.

How do I loop `data` and sum it's elements if I only have a pointer to it ?

Comment: If you only have a plain pointer you can't since you do not know the length.

Comment: You have two ways: either store the size of array or place *the last* element (say, -1), which will indicate, that there are no more elements in the array.

Comment: I do know the length let me update the question.

Comment: Well if you know the length then just a simple `for` loop will do. Do you need this to work on arrays of any type? Then you can use templates.

Comment: I need this for a case where I have `(BYTE*)msr.pData` as a pointer to a large array. The data represented are `unsigned int`s.

Comment: @PinkTurtle ok so you are getiing a byte pointer and length in bytes, I can make an example for this, but then for others you should change the example to show that you do not expose the actual data type.

Comment: Well I wrote the cast myself so it could be `(unsigned int*)msr.pData` as well. I was interested in how you read `BYTE`s back into `unsigned int`s.

Comment: @PinkTurtle if I understood everything correctly my answer should help you. However you cannot do this if you don't know the underlying type since you need to know to what data type to perform the cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of doing this with a for loop and using a template to handle different data types, but this only works if you know the actual data type since you need to cast to it:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo {
private:
    unsigned int data[5];

public:
    foo()
    {
        // MSVC2012 does not support explicit array initializers so I'll have to do it the ugly way
        data[0] = 1;
        data[1] = 2;
        data[2] = 3;
        data[3] = 4;
        data[4] = 5;
    }

    unsigned char* getpData () {
        // as far as I understand from the comments the actual data type is not exposed
        return reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(data);
    }

    unsigned int getDataByteLength () {
        return sizeof(data);
    }
};

template<typename T>
T calculate_sum(T* data, unsigned int byte_length)
{
    T sum = 0;
    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < byte_length / sizeof(T); index++)
    {
        sum += data[index];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    foo f;
    // cast back to the represented type
    unsigned int* data = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(f.getpData());
    unsigned int byte_length = f.getDataByteLength();
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < byte_length / sizeof(unsigned int); index++)
    {
        sum += data[index];
    }
    std::cout << "Sum with loop: " << sum << ", sum with template: " << calculate_sum(data, byte_length) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here is the data structure I am actually working with : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx I need to understand your example and implement it ;)

Comment: Well this is a bit different opera - are you aware that the pitch can actually be larger than the image width if there is a need to pad the image?

Comment: I don't even know what pitch means. Im trying to deduce data dimensions from my image size and `RowPitch` / `DepthPitch`. My image is `1280 * 720`, `RowPitch` is `5120` and `DepthPitch` `3686400`. `5120 / 4` is `1280`, and `3686400` is `1280 * 720 * 4`. Sounds aligned =)

Comment: @PinkTurtle my comment was meant to be simply informative:)

Comment: No offense. So I guess I would rather iterate my `pData` with a `clientWidth` (window width in pixels) variable instead of `rowPitch`. Upon adding 1 pixel to the window width my `rowPitch` is now indeed 5248 (1312 * 4).

Comment: Yes that would be more correct. However - to at least show that the scenarios where padding exceeds the width are related to specific use cases an maybe in your case can be ignored I should demonstrate at least one. So one such example is when you encode NV12 image to H.264 video - H.264 needs the dimensions of the image to be 16 aligned and if the original NV12 image is not, you must pad it.